# Do I have to DISPOSE and how should I do it?

Tags: vb.net, dispose

I zoom an image with the following code

```
While PictureBox1.Image.Height < ScreenHeight
      PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Image1, PictureBox1.Image.Width * 1.003, PictureBox1.Image.Height * 1.003)
      Me.PictureBox1.Update()
End While
```

Do I need to `dispose` within the loop (but how do I preserve my image then?) or is it sufficient to dispose only once outside the loop?

Do I use `Picturebox1.Image.Dispose()`

Do I also need to use `PictureBox1.Image = Nothing`

Thanks for any useful information

Comment: The "visual-studio-2012" tag is NOT relivant - remove it.  Add a language tag (VB?).

Comment: Dim bmp = new Bitmap(...): PictureBox1.Image.Dispose(): PictureBox1.Image = bmp

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well

```
Dim Width, Height As Integer
Width = PictureBox1.Image.Width
Height = PictureBox1.Image.Height
While Height < ScreenHeight And (Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.Timer - StartTime) < ScreenSaverDuration
      PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Image1, Width * 1.003, Height * 1.003)
      Width = PictureBox1.Image.Width
      Height = PictureBox1.Image.Height
      Me.PictureBox1.Update()
      PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Height As Integer = PictureBox1.Image.Height
Dim Width As Integer = PictureBox1.Image.Width
While PictureBox1.Image.Height < ScreenHeight
    Height *= 1.003
    Width *= 1.003
End While
PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(Image1, Width, Height)
PictureBox1.Update()
```